# I need to download Ubuntu onto a USB drive to load it into a Toshiba Satellite 55c through BIOS

Tags: usb, bios

My Toshiba Satellite 55c has no ROM drive and the OS is wiped completely from it. I need to download Ubuntu onto a USB drive to load it into my computer through BIOS. How do I need to  configure it and what other downloads do I need, like Rufus maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Download the Linux version you need. Then use LinuxLive USB creator to create a bootable USB get it here: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/fr/
You will need a working computer to do so.
When your bootable USB is done, boot your Toshiba with the USB stick in your computer. From the boot menu (You might have to use F12 or DEL to access it), select USB to boot from, install Linux. At the end of the installation, Linux will ask you to restart your computer. Do so and upon rebooting, access your boot menu again, then select your hard drive as a boot. You can now enjoy your new Linux computer.